# How to grant Google Apps Script app permission in try catch error block

Tags: google-apps-script, google-account

```
try {  
   ...
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Failed to get claim search list, error: %s', e.message);

    // email the notice
    var recipient = 'xxxxxxx';
    var subject = 'Failed list';
    var body = e.message;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

    return false;
  }
```

So in my Google Apps Script app, I only send out email in error case. Actually, this

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
```

never got chance to run. Due to that, I never be able to give the permission to allow this app to send email under my Google account.

Then when I schedule this app to auto run daily. In very rare cases, the error happened but the permission for this app to send email for my account was never granted. So email was not sent out due to that.

So I have to manually simulate the error case to grant the permission. There are anyways that I can add the permission through this control panel,

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Or it is always run the app manually and grant the permission when the statements we just run need the permission.

For a "complicated" app, it is hard to simulate all the uses cases and trigger all the permission grant windows this script may need.

Do I have to write a dummy function the only purpose is triggering all the permissions grant windows?

Comment: Sometimes if you approve the permissions, and then add more code later, then the permissions need to be re-approved.  It shouldn't matter that `MailApp` is only in a `catch` block.  But you can try adding `\\MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);`  as a comment somewhere outside of the catch block. Your "Apps with access to your account" dashboard can't set the permission, but you can manually set the permissions in the "appsscript.json" file.  In the code editor, click "View" and "Show Manifest File"  Then look in File->Project Properties->Scopes.

Comment: Links for what @Sandy said: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Automatic scope detection does not require the word syntax to be executable or reachable.